# Flash Builder plugin

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

I know that this is not a programming related question but what is the name of plugin in this video: http://johnlindquist.com/2010/01/21/as3-signals-tutorial/.

Here is screenshot I've took: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBIJm.png
It is used to auto complete code generation as is is shown in movie (for example to create local variable after clicking key combination ad the end of line).

It would make my life easier :)

I'm currently using flash builder 4.6 on windows 7 x64. Plugins that I have installed are: SourceMate and CodeFormatter

Maybe this isn't a plugin after all, maybe I must install eclipse and flash builder as a plugin. Help me with this one please.

Comment: Found it: It is FDT5 - http://fdt.powerflasher.com/.
Sorry for trouble, but maybe someone know plugin for flash builder that has those code complete features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in comment to my question I found out that application that was used in this video is FDT5. I hope that someday these features will be build into Flash Builder.